# Store result as a list using prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I wanted the result to be stored in a list.

```
subject(english, 2).
subject(math,2).
subject(science,2).

get_subject(subject, level) :- subject(subject,level) .
```

when I have this query:

```
?-get_subject(X,2).
```

it gives me the output:

```
X = english;
X = math;
X = science.
```

but i wanted the output to be list like this:
[english, math, science]
is it possible to do that in prolog?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use `findall`:

```
?- findall(X, get_subject(X,2), Subjects).
```

Also your `get_subject` definition should use capital-cased words for variables:

```
get_subject(Subject, Level) :- subject(Subject, Level).
```

What Prolog system do you use so your small-cased code works?

And of course your `get_subject` doesn't do anything useful, you can delete its definition and just use `subject` directly:

```
?- findall(X, subject(X,2), Subjects).
Subjects = [english, math, science].
```